# Column field is not recognized/not defined

Tags: django, mongodb, python-3.7

I have this model and here is my query - the error shows "submission_date" is not defined. However the "overall_rating" - which is another column, is working fine. I do not understand the reason.

```
class businessdata(models.Model):    
    submission_date = models.DateTimeField(null = False)
    product_id = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    model_number = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    upc  = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    overall_rating = models.IntegerField(null = False)
```

So this query works...

```
categoryResult = businessdata.objects.filter(overall_rating = rating, product_name='XYZ')
```

But this does not work...

```
categoryResult = 
  businessdata.objects.filter(submission_date >= fromdate, submission_date <= todate, overall_rating = 5).values(submission_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')).annotate(count = Count(submission_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))
```

It says...
name 'sumission_date' not defined

Answer (score 2):

You cannot compare dates this way inside the query, try this instead:

```
  businessdata.objects.filter(submission_date__gte=fromdate, submission_date__lte=todate, overall_rating = 5)
```

Essentially replacing `>=` with `__gte` and `<=` with `__lte`

[Here's the docs on date comparisons](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#date)

Comment: Well I tried that too... I tried this... and it still shows "submission_date"  not defined in the next line...



        categoryResult = businessdata.objects.filter(submission_date__gte=fromDate, submission_date__lte = toDate, overall_rating = rating)\
        .values(submission_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')).annotate(count = Count(submission_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))


in this section...


values(submission_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')).annotate(count = Count(submission_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))

Comment: Try removing the `strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: Sure - thanks.... let me try but I need only the %Y-%m-%d instead of the whole hour minute etc... as I need to do a group by count... it has to be date-wise..

Comment: I removed the strftime('%Y-%m-%d') Still shows this...

Exception Value:
name 'submission_date' is not defined

Comment: Try putting `submission_date` in quotes, like this: `values("submission_date")`

Answer (score 0):

> It says... name 'sumission_date' not defined

- Your field name is a su**b**mission_date

Check your syntax.

Comment: Sorry it is typo in writing this question (I should have copy pasted the error instead of hand-writing it) - in my query it is submission date...